# iOS app loses tab bar from feed

Tags: bug, ios-app, ios-app-feed

When selecting a site from the feed (by tapping its icon), the tab bar is missing.

> [image]

<sup>Beta 1.0.1.85</sup>

Comment: Technically, it doesn't lose it because it never had it. The app exists right now in a kind of ugly state where the feed exists as a feed inside a navigation controller and sites exist as tab controllers containing navigation controllers containing question list, etc.  Jumping from the feed to the full site would break the back button so it just shows the question list.  This is by no means perfect.